# Control vertical spacing between paragraphs in org-mode export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to export org-mode to PDF or preferably ODT format. How do I set arbitrarily vertical space, e.g space before paragraph 6pt, space after 12pt. Is there any global option for me to do this?